# For loop causes crash

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

In the class below, the constructor crashes:

```ruby
class Locations
    def initialize
        @index = [{}]
        file = File.new(NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('suburbs', ofType: 'txt'), 'r')
        while (line = file.gets)
            location = Location.parse(line)
            for x in 0...@index.length do
            end
        end
        file.close
        self
    end
end
```

If I remove the for loop, it doesn't crash:

```ruby
class Locations
    def initialize
        @index = [{}]
        file = File.new(NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('suburbs', ofType: 'txt'), 'r')
        while (line = file.gets)
            location = Location.parse(line)
        end
        file.close
        self
    end
end
```

And if I swap the order of the for loop and the `location` assignment, it also doesn't crash:

```ruby
class Locations
    def initialize
        @index = [{}]
        file = File.new(NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('suburbs', ofType: 'txt'), 'r')
        while (line = file.gets)
            for x in 0...@index.length do
            end
            location = Location.parse(line)
        end
        file.close
        self
    end
end
```

Any idea?

**Edit:** Here's the console output:

```
*** simulator session ended with error: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 "The simulated application quit." UserInfo=0x10012c9d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The simulated application quit., DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-1}
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="/Applications/Xcode.a...]
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:112:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p385/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => simulator

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: what error you got,give it also to us.. what contains the `for` loop?

Comment: I cannot replicate the fault from the code sample. Stack trace might help, also you have a call to other code I have no idea about - can you still cause the fault without calls to `Location.parse(line)`? What happens if you just substitute in `location = Object.new` ?

Comment: Question updated with console output. There is nothing in the for loop. I actually ran these three versions of the `Locations` class verbatim.

Comment: @NeilSlater, it crashes when I execute `location = Object.new` instead of `location = `Location.parse(line)`.

Comment: Re-ran with `--trace`. Stack trace added to question.

Comment: @Steve Taylor: I don't see the call to `new` in the stack trace. I am not able to replicate the fault with very similar Ruby code directly. It's an oddity. What Ruby version are you running? Are you able to run your code outside of `rake`? In your phone sim environment, do you have ability to output to console to aid with debugging?

Comment: I'm running RubyMotion 2.4. This code is executed from `AppDelegate.application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Are you trying to reproduce it from regular (not RubyMotion) Ruby?

Comment: Ah, very interesting. After adding log statements, it looks like it's choking on the last iteration of the while loop. I placed the logging statement before, inside and after the for loop and it printed every single line including the last. Without a working debugger and `rescue` not rescuing, I can't tell exactly where it's crashing.

Comment: If you are running this from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption:` and that loop takes more than 5 seconds or so, the iOS _watchdog_ will kill you unless you have presented some UI. Try moving the code out of the start of the app, and see if it still happens.

Comment: It takes about one second. I originally executed it in the `viewDidLoad` of a view controller being pushed onto a `UINavigationController`. It also crashes in that context.